# Access linkedin info not working using PassportJS + NodeJs + Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am implementing Passportjs w/ node in my Angular application to retrieve the users linkedIn info such as name, current positions, etc... here's the scenario.

User NOT already logged into LinkedIn -> redirects user to linkedIn sign in page. (Great!)

User already logged into LinkedIn -> redirects to page saying "LinkedIn Verification Failed" (WTF?)

**Code:**

Upon button click in my Angular controller:

```
$scope.verifyLinkedIn = function(){
  $window.location.href = '/auth/linkedin' ;
};
```

Then this is what my node routes.js file looks like for the linkedIn Passport:

```
{
    path: '/auth/linkedin',
    httpMethod: 'GET',
    middleware: [passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
        successRedirect: '/edit_roommate',
        failureRedirect: '/edit_roommate'
    })]
},
{
    path: '/auth/linkedin/callback',
    httpMethod: 'GET',
    middleware: [function (req, res) {
        console.log('/auth/linkedin/callback - req.url: ' + req.url);
        AuthCtrl.loginWithLinkedIn(req, res, function(err, res)
        {
            console.log('done!');
            //res.render('search');
        });
    }]
},
```

From this point on the page redirects to:

```
http://www.apartmate.com/auth/linkedin/callback?code=AQQ9UPfnVSTlaHv8OYzPdnIcIt0KtpGW7OCbv3ngolCoR3mWGNADymFwGckWEU7RB1VMthn77ILPaxHtlO3N9Kx-NghPtGbGrIYxkyAzZzyNdZM-Fv8&state=vSMzPEsAQhviuHqgF8xEGhfQ
```

With the page saying "LinkedIn Verification Failed" and the console wiped clean. Am I missing something? Is my implementation incorrect? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.